# Spyder does not run new changes in code

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to update Python 3.6 code with Spyder 3.2.4 (through Anaconda), but when I make a change to the code that I am working on and attempt to run it, it will run the code that I started the session with.  Does anyone know of any solutions to this?

Comment: This happens to me sometimes. Just restart spyder

Comment: That's what I've been doing, even restarted the computer, and the problem persists.  It's weird though, it just started happening.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) It's very odd that the problem persists after you restart the computer. It should work only by restarting the kernel associated to the console you are your code into.

Comment: Please try to update Spyder to its latest version (3.2.8) and try again. We added a way to reload code without restarting Spyder or a kernel in one of our last versions, so that could solve your problem.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change the directory of .py that you are working on. Right click to sample.py(which is above of console) and choose set console working directory. You can apply it for each python file while working on it.
I had also same problem and did that , now it is okey.